# JSONB array contains like OR and AND operators

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

Consider a table `temp (jsondata jsonb)`

Postgres provides a way to query jsonb array object for contains check using

```
SELECT jsondata 
FROM temp 
WHERE (jsondata->'properties'->'home') ? 'football'
```

But, we can't use LIKE operator for array contains. One way to get LIKE in the array contains is using -

```
SELECT jsondata 
FROM temp,jsonb_array_elements_text(temp.jsondata->'properties'->'home') 
WHERE value like '%foot%'
```

OR operation with LIKE can be achieved by using -

```
SELECT DISTINCT jsondata 
FROM temp,jsonb_array_elements_text(temp.jsondata->'properties'->'home') 
WHERE value like '%foot%' OR value like 'stad%'
```

But, I am unable to perform AND operation with LIKE operator in JSONB array contains.

Comment: Are you sure you have any 'home' value that contains "foot" and begins with "stad"?

Comment: json looks like - {"properties":{"home":["football","stadium","16"]}} I want to perform and operation like - %foot% and %stad% on home array

Comment: But then you don't have _one_ value with both which you want when your using `AND`

Comment: Correct. That's why I am unable to perform this operation. I just tried this option. But, if there is some better way without using value, then that would be better as well. All, I want to achieve is to perform LIKE operation on JSONB array with OR and AND operations.

Answer (score 1):

After unnesting the array with `jsonb_array_elements()` you can check `values` meeting one of the conditions and sum them in groups by original rows, example:

```
drop table if exists temp;
create table temp(id serial primary key, jsondata jsonb);
insert into temp (jsondata) values
    ('{"properties":{"home":["football","stadium","16"]}}'),
    ('{"properties":{"home":["football","player","16"]}}'),
    ('{"properties":{"home":["soccer","stadium","16"]}}');

select jsondata
from temp 
cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(temp.jsondata->'properties'->'home') 
group by jsondata 
-- or better:
-- group by id
having sum((value like '%foot%' or value like 'stad%')::int) = 2

                        jsondata                         
---------------------------------------------------------
 {"properties": {"home": ["football", "stadium", "16"]}}
(1 row)
```

---

Update. The above query may be expensive with a large dataset. There is a simplified but faster solution. You can cast the array to text and apply `like` to it, e.g.:

```
select jsondata
from temp 
where jsondata->'properties'->>'home' like all('{%foot%, %stad%}');

                        jsondata                         
---------------------------------------------------------
 {"properties": {"home": ["football", "stadium", "16"]}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: This I already tried. But, this involves join and group by which are heavy operations. So, I would prefer something which doesn't involve this operation. just using LIKE and AND operator.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following, but it was a bit fiddly. There's probably a better way but this is working I think.

The idea is to find the matching JSON array entries, then collect the results. In the join condition we check the "matches" array has the expected number of entries.

```
CREATE TABLE temp (jsondata jsonb);

INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('{"properties":{"home":["football","stadium",16]}}');

SELECT jsondata FROM temp t
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT array_agg(value) AS matches
    FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(t.jsondata->'properties'->'home')
    WHERE value LIKE '%foo%' OR value LIKE '%sta%'
    LIMIT 1        
) l ON array_length(matches, 1) = 2;

                           jsondata                        
-------------------------------------------------------
 {"properties": {"home": ["football", "stadium", 16]}}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0cec40aae8c2b6008cd9aba611278166)

I would cast the array into text. Then you are able to search for keywords with every string operator.

Disadvantage: because it was an array the text contains characters like braces and commas. So it's not that simple to search for keyword with a certain beginning (`ABC%`): You always have to search like `%ABC%`

```
SELECT jsondata
FROM (
    SELECT 
        jsondata, 
        jsondata->'properties'->>'home' as a
    FROM 
        temp
)s
WHERE 
    a LIKE '%stad%' AND a LIKE '%foot%'
```