# PostgreSQL reverse LIKE with patterns in json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This question is related to [PostgreSQL Reverse LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738114/postgresql-reverse-like/45740280)

I have a table `a` containing a json column `a.matchers`. `a.matchers` is an array of objects each of which has property `pattern`
Given an `inputString` I would like to get all rows where at least one of the `matchers[].pattern`'s would match `inputString LIKE '%{pattern}%'`

So basically (as pseudoquery):

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
WHERE 
    'inputStringABC' LIKE ANY('%' || json_array_elements(a.matchers)->>'pattern' || '%')
```

Is this possible?

p.s.: PostgreSQL version being 9.6.3

**edit: more extensive status quo description:**

Table a:

```
           Column            |            Type             |                   Modifiers                   | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 uuid                         | uuid                        | not null default uuid_generate_v4()           | plain    |              |
 matchers                     | json                        |                                               | extended |              |
```

JSON structure in column matchers:

```
[
    {
        pattern: string;
    }
]
```

Example use case:

I have a string "Some trees look nicer than others" and following rows in table `a`:

- `uuid: "123...", matchers: [{ pattern: "trees" }]`
- `uuid: "987...", matchers: [{ pattern: "bees" }, { pattern: "plants" }]`

The query should return row with uuid `"123..."` as `trees` occurs in `"Some trees look nicer than others"`

**Edit2:**

final query which worked for me thanks to s-man

```
SELECT DISTINCT                                                  
    uuid,
    pattern
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        jsonb_array_elements(a.matchers)->>'pattern' as pattern  
    FROM a
) s
WHERE 
    'Some trees look nicer than others' LIKE '%' || pattern || '%'
```

Comment: Please provide an example. Especially for json objects the exact structure is very important to know.

Comment: Edited the question adding more details but in the meantime you provided an answer already ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Table**:

```
id   matchers
1    [{"abc": 1, "pattern": "ABC"}, {"pattern": "ABAB"}, {"cde": "FOO", "pattern": "AABB"}]
2    [{"pattern": "AB"}, {"cde": "BAR", "pattern": "CDE"}]
3    [{"abc": 2, "pattern": "CD"}, {"pattern": "FG"}]
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT                                                  -- C
    id,
    matchers
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        jsonb_array_elements(a.matchers)->>'pattern' as pattern  -- A
    FROM a
) s
WHERE 
    pattern LIKE '%AB%'                                          -- B
```

A: `jsonb_array_elements` expands the json array to one row per array element. The `->>` operator gives the value of the pattern attribute contained by each array element as text.

B: Filtering the text values with `LIKE` operator

C: Because the table is expanded we have to reduce it again since we want only the original columns which we saved through the subquery in every row.

**Result**:

```
id   matchers
1    [{"abc": 1, "pattern": "ABC"}, {"pattern": "ABAB"}, {"cde": "FOO", "pattern": "AABB"}]
2    [{"pattern": "AB"}, {"cde": "BAR", "pattern": "CDE"}]
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0de01550327f1d49939226110c540b29)

---

If your column is of type `json` instead of `jsonb` you have to use `json_array_elements` of course.

---

**Edit:** After making the question more clearer it came out that the use case for the pattern is other way round. So the expected result can be achieved by changing the `WHERE` clause into:

```
'long input string including pattern' LIKE '%' || pattern || '%'
```

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400276/jsonb-array-contains-like-or-and-and-operators)

Comment: Thank you a lot.
Ok that makes sense. My use case would require a reverse LIKE I.e. I dont want to match patterns which contain the fixed input string, but rather match rows containing a pattern which is contained in the input string.
Your answer provided the solution though - I had tried without an expanding subquery before which hadnt worked. Adding final query to question.